# how to aggregate if there are two conditions to be met in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hi im new to mongodb and I am confused in aggregating when there are two conditions to be met

The two conditions are:
The lowest score and the type should be homework

This is my schema design:

```
    "_id" : 0,
"name" : "aimee Zank",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 1.463179736705023
        },
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 11.78273309957772
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 6.676176060654615
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 35.8740349954354
        }
    ]
}
```

What I plan to do is to query the lowest homework score. So in my schema design above I plan to query the third element because it is the lowest score of the homework.

My mongodb query I have made right now is this:

```
db.students.aggregate( [ 
    { "$unwind": "$scores" },
    { "$match" : {"type" : "homework"}},
    {"$group": { '_id':'$_id', 'score': {'$min': "$scores.score" } } }
    ])
```

but all I get after doing this query is:

```
{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at your condition in "match": you have to specify the full path.

That means you should do like this:

`[{"$unwind": "$scores"}, 
{"$match": {"scores.type":"homework"}}, 
{"$group": { '_id':'$_id', 'score': {'$min': "$scores.score" } }}]`

notice "scores.type"

Answer (score 1):

i hope this help
you have to use the and operator
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: Thanks sir but this is not the answer, I tried it out and it didn't work out for me because I get an error regarding use $and in group. my mistake was having a typo which ahrzg has specified. Thanks!